# Convert .rules file to Visual Studio 2010 .targets file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, custom-build-step

I'm trying to se flex and bison in Visual Studio 2010. I found a .rules file on the web, but it is only useable in vs2k5/2k8. How do I convert it to the newer, '.targets' format?

Here's the file:

http://pastebin.com/Xxt6hGdb

Are there any tools for this?

Thank you!

Yvan

Answer (score 2):

I used the TinyMath project available in the below link to test that.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730877%28vs.80%29.aspx
VS2010 automatically converts that to the .targets format.

Comment: yes, but I don't have a project with this file. I want to start a new project, and cannot reuse an old.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio 2010 does this automatically when you migrate the project.

Comment: I don't have a project with this file - I want to start a new project, using these settings.